# Google Spreadsheet: How To Counting Rows with specific date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

scenario: I'm using a Google form to track my calls per day with a timestamp, person called, event, and additional information which are then store in a spreadsheet. 
need: At the end of the day I wanna know how many calls I placed and how often a certain event has happened in an additional column of my spreadsheet. 
me: I don't know how to do this
question: how can I do this? What do I need?

I thought about counting the rows in column A (which has got the timestamp) somehow like this
    `=COUNTIF(A:A;"DATE=TODAY")`

Thanks in advance. If I left out some information needed for answering this question please let me know.

**UPDATE 08-02-2014**
Thank you for your answer. I decided to make another sheet as my dashboard where I just count rows for the weeks, as I saw that they are sufficient as my key numbers. This is how I decided to do it
`=COUNTIF(A$MONDAY:A$FRIDAY;"*reached*")`
*Note:* I used * because there are more scenarios of how a client could be reached in the detailed spreadsheet, but I just need an overview of all clients reached. Instead of `$MONDAY`and `$FRIDAY` I use the number of the row for start and end of the week.

For the calls placed I simple use `=COUNT(…)`.

Thank you for all your answers! Maybe I will add an array function someday ;)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles

Answer (score 2):

I hope that you are trying to make a dashboard on the spreadsheet it self to get statistics on your call centers daily performance. You can use below formula to get the count.

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,TODAY())
```

Please note that all Ms Excel formulas are available in new version of Google spreadsheet. Also if you like to do some complicated works then lookout Google App Script UiApp or HTML services. Both are very interesting.

I would also like to say few other words. People are coming here because they have tried their level best, failed and they cant figure out how to proceed further. Some time we all get stuck up because of an error on ';' or '}'. So, my point is if someone is asking help. we should help then and not give him another link with no direct answer.

Happy Learning, BIRCHWOOD. Keep going.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much!Sadly `=COUNTIF(A:A,TODAY())` doesn't work, because column A is structured like this `DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS`. Can I add a * or something else to today? This is driving me crazy :D Currently the rows are summed up by hand in column F by simply using `=F$+1`

Comment: Okey cool.. I have tried to recreate your issue. I have used the formula =COUNT(FILTER(A:A, Datevalue(A:A)=DATEVALUE(TODAY()))) to get the count. It is a combined formula of COUNT and FILTER. Also make sure that your date column is having "dates" and not "strings" in the form of dates. I hope it makes sense..